# Cache file for x minutes php

Tags: php, fwrite

I am trying to cache the prices of items from another site using the following code.

```
$cache_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/prices.json';
if (file_exists($cache_file) && (filemtime($cache_file) > (time() - 60 * 9))) {
$file = file_get_contents($cache_file);
} else {
 $url = 'http://csgo.backpack.tf/api/IGetPrices/v4/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
 $file = curl_load($url);
 $fp = fopen('/prices.json', 'w');
 fwrite($fp, $file, LOCK_EX);
 fclose($fp);
}
```

The api key is correct, yet it still will not write. The result returned by the api is a json string. I want to write it the file so I can decode and use it to price items. Can anyone help me out here, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to write to the filesystem's base directory (`/`), to which you don't (and shouldn't) have write access from a web-accessible PHP script. You need to construct a proper path for `fopen()`:

```
fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/prices.json', 'w');
```

Note: you used the above path once, when checking for the file's existence, but then used just`/prices.json` later.

An even better, less repetitive, way to do it is to use the variable you already set, `$cache_file`:

```
fopen($cache_file, 'w');
```